# Avoid System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException by detecting a system folder before writing a file

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, windows-vista

I have a vb .net application where the user can choose a directory into which an excel file is written. If the user selects a system directory (yes, my users do this, don't ask me why) then a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException is thrown at runtime.

I am handling this exception telling the user to please select another directory.

**My application works fine as it is, but I would really like to know how to detect if the directory will allow writing a file into it before an exception in thrown.**

And no, using System.IO.DirectoryInfo doesnt do the trick... or maybe it does but I am just not good enough.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to create a dummy file in the destination folder, which if successful you then delete - and if it (the create) fails, chances are high that you won't be able to save your .xls(x) file there!  Am sure that DirectoryInfo will permit the detection of system files / folders, however, the dummy file trick is a cheap way of checking permissions on any folder.

Comment: Yes, i thought of the dummy file of course, but it's kinda the same i have now: handle the exception thrown at runtime. I just would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do that. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: FileIOPermission (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx) sounds promising, but looks to me as though all roads lead to an exception being thrown if the permission is denied.  Are you using a SaveFileDialog?  If so, does this have a property to allow checking the destination before accepting the users selection?  OnFileOk looks like a suitable hook into verifying the selected file.

Comment: Actually no SaveFileDialog... I have a settings screen where the user selects a default directory. I am using OpenFileDialog for the user to pick the folder... as FolderBrowserDialog is so ugggghhh.. What I want to do is preciselt use the OnFileOk event to check. I will have a look at the FileIOPermission Class you sugested and let you all know. Thank you!